# Select features covering an image (Google Earth Engine)

Tags: google-earth-engine, filter, image

I have a feature collection (grids) and an image. Any ideas on how to filter only features that cover the image (only the unmasked part of the image which appears in the map layer)?

Here's the code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/16bfa4e762138a463bfe7bc3e2c738bd

```
var biome = ee.Image("OpenLandMap/PNV/PNV_BIOME-TYPE_BIOME00K_C/v01");
var tropical = biome.updateMask(biome.gte(1).and(biome.lte(3)));

var grid = american.coveringGrid('EPSG:4326', 500000); 

Map.addLayer(grid);
Map.addLayer(tropical);
```

For example, I want to select features only in the red part.
[image]

Comment: You need to include a script in the question. A link to script in the Code Editor of GEE are also recomended.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I added the script link.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any accurate and efficient ways to do that at scale. But this might be enough for your use-case?

```
var filtered = tropical
  .reduceRegions({
    collection: grid, 
    reducer: ee.Reducer.count(), 
    scale: 1000, 
  })
  .filter(ee.Filter.gt('count', 0))
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/fc4d16a179a1aa0f829f816238d52b4b

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you very much!